# "string indices must be integers" error when loading in JSON

Tags: python

I want to access items from a new dictionary called `conversations` by implementing a for loop.

```
{" conversations": [
{"tag": "greeting",
"user": ["Hi", " What's your name?", " How are you?", "Hello", "Good day"],
"response": ["Hello, my name is Rosie. Nice to see you", "Good to see you again", " How can I help you?"],
"context_set": ""
},
{"tag": "Good-bye",
"user": ["Bye", "See you", "Goodbye"],
"response": ["Thanks for visiting our company", "Have a nice day", "Good-bye."]
},
{"tag": "thanks",
"user": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful", "Appreciated your service" ],
"response": ["Glad to help!", "My pleasure", "You’re welcome."]
}
]
}
```

The code I use to load the dictionary in a notebook is

```
    file_name = 'dialogue.txt'
    with open(file_name, encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
        dialogue_text = f.read()
```

This line of code does not return any results when trying to access the dictionary.

```
  for k in dialogue_text:
  print(k)
```

My intention is to write this code by implementing tokenization and stemming, but it returned an error

```
words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

for conversation in dialogue_text["conversations"]:
    for user in dialogue_text["user"]:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(user)
        words.extend(words)
        docs_x.append(words)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])words = [stemmer.stemWord(w.lower()) for w in words if w 
     != "?"]
     words = sorted(list(set(words)))labels = sorted(labels)
```

Error Message:

```
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-12-d42234f8e809> in <module>()
     10 docs_y = []
     11 
     ---> 12 for conversation in dialogue_text["conversations"]:
     13     for user in dialogue_text["user"]:
     14         words = nltk.word_tokenize(user)

     TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What code should I write to resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like a JSON file -- why not use the `json` module?

Comment: `f.read()` gives you a string.  You should be able to turn it into a dictionary by calling `json.loads()` on that string.

Comment: dialogue_text = f.read() will assign file content to dialogue_text as str type, you need convert dialogue_text to dict type.

Comment: In your original JSON object your have `" conversations"`, note the space in front. This is in addition to what others have pointed out already.

Comment: It's in txt format.

Comment: `.txt` is a file extension, which is distinct from its _contents_ that can be interpreted as JSON in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `json` module to load in JSON data as opposed to reading in the file line-by-line. Whatever procedure you build yourself is likely to be fragile and less efficient.

Here is the looping structure that you're looking for:

```py
import json

with open('input.json') as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    # Spaces were originally in the key name.
    for conversation in data[' conversations']: 
        for user_words in conversation['user']:
            # Do stuff with user_words ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
import json

dialogue_text = json.load(open("dialogue.txt", encoding='utf8'))

for conversation in dialogue_text[" conversations"]:
    for user in conversation['user']:
        print(user)
```

Output:

```
Hi
What's your name?
 How are you?
Hello
Good day
Bye
See you
Goodbye
Thanks
Thank you
That's helpful
Appreciated your service
```

Comment: I received an error:

Comment: /usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 16 column 55 (char 738)

Comment: maybe add "encoding='utf8'" would work for you~

Comment: It still didn't work for me. Idk, I'm getting the error again. Thanks a lot for your help.